# Div on the bottom of fancybox popup

Tags: fancybox, fixed

I am using Fancybox (fancyapps.com) to use popup ajax windows. I need to place a div in the lower right corner of the popup but I do not know how to do it.

I tried position:fixed but then the div aligns to the bottom of the screen not the popup bottom. I am using Ajax and not iframe to show content in popup.

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to place the div inside the outer popup div. Assuming the div has id="lower-right-corner". Then the css would be:

```
#lower-right-corner{

position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom:0;

}
```

That is assuming that the popup outer div has a position other than static.
You can find more info about css positioning here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp